# How to do form field validation in node.js ?(express-validator)

Tags: node.js, express, validation

In My package.json files

```
  "express": "~4.9.0",
  "express-validator": "~2.7.0"
   .
   .
   .
```

In my app.js file

```
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
.
.
.
app.use(expressValidator);
```

When i go to browser, the respective page is not displayed? It is continuously loading. After remove express validator relevant code, the page render properly.

Comment: Maybe you can derive some use from the code I posted last night:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41502491/issue-with-ignored-field-validation-in-node-js-express-validator-on-user-registr

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have bodyParser installed.

Express-validator recommends that it is called immediately after bodyParser in app.js.

- Quote: "this line must be immediately after any of the bodyParser middlewares!"
- Reference: https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator

> Example:

```
 // bodyParser
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

 // Express-validator
 app.use(expressValidator({
   errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
       var   namespace = param.split('.'),
             root      = namespace.shift(),
             formParam = root;

     while(namespace.length) {
       formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
     }
     return {
       param : formParam,
       msg   : msg,
       value : value
     };
   }
 }));
```

Comment: I'm getting an impression that you have actually posted a comment as an answer as you don't have sufficient reputation to comment on a post. Such commentaries as an answer get flagged for deletion if they are not relevant. Please invest more time and contribute on the website so that you gain suffcient reputation to be able to comment as well. Happy programming!

Comment: Yea I would have. I haven't been making garbage questions to get my reputation up so I'm just suffering over here :)

I actually didn't even realize this was a super old question because I just clicked in the related column down to the right while looking at my newest question, and I was like 'ooh I might be able to help him'... lol. I only clicked it because it had zero answers.

Stackoverflow is amazing, but a little savage at times.

Comment: You are just 20 reputation away. You will be there soon. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up as well.

Comment: And in my defense, it is a possible answer considering he gave terrible expansion, and based on my recent reading, I can say that express-validator needs to be right after bodyParser in app.js.

I guess I too was lacking verbosity. I'll edit my answer to include this and improve context.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not much code to work with. But you could try it with:

```
app.use(expressValidator());
```

instead of

```
app.use(expressValidator);
```